# Object Fields Missing in Autogenerated Mutation Input for GraphQL AppSync

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a custom GraphQL schema for a blogging application for my ReactJS app. The main model type is Post.

Post contains a number of properties that have a custom type eg Gallery: [MediaObject]. The majority of these properties with custom types are missing from the automatically generated CreatePostInput by AWS Amplify CLI. This means that I cannot create a Post object that has these properties with custom type.

The lack of these custom type properties is evident in the AppSync console, under Queries. In the Explorer, go to Mutations, click on CreatePost mutation, and you will see that 6 of the 21 properties for Post are missing. The missing properties are tags, attributes, seo, featuredImage, gallery and createdBy.

They are also missing in the autogenerated graphql schema in api > build > schema.graphql in the  react app.

I have made multiple clean projects from scratch, and the problem is reproducible. I have  updated the amplify cli to 4.51.2 and still no luck.

I would expect the CreatePostInput to have the associated inputs for all of the fields, not just `comments` (see the autogenerated CreatePostInput below) eg: `attribute: AttributeInput`, but these are not generated either. This would allow me to create a Post object that has these custom fields populated. However, only the `CommentInput` has been generated. What am I doing wrong here, or have I misunderstood something?

Thanks!

Below is my gql schema and both the autogenerated CreatePostInput and CommentInput:

```
type Post @model {
    id: ID
    createdBy: User
    createdAt: AWSDateTime
    updatedAt:AWSDateTime
    type: PostType!
    title: String!
    status: Status
    content: String!
    excerpt: String
    slug: AWSURL
    wordpressId: Int
    wordpressImageURLs: [AWSURL]
    author: String
    likes: Int
    tags: [Tag]
    attributes: Attribute
    seo: Seo
    featuredImage: MediaObject
    gallery: [MediaObject]
    comments: [Comment]
    numberOfComments: Int

}

type User @model {
    id: ID
    username: String!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: AWSEmail!
    avatar: MediaObject
    location: String
    createdAt: AWSDateTime
    updatedAt: AWSDateTime
    Posts: [Post]
}

type Tag @model {
    id: ID
    postIds: [ID]
    name: String!
}

type Attribute @model {
    id: ID
    postId: ID
    link: String
    imgUrl: AWSURL
    ogImage: AWSURL
    ogDescription: String
    canonicalLink: AWSURL
}

type Seo @model {
    id: ID
    postId: ID
    metaRobotsNoIndex: String
    metaRobotsNoFollow: String
    canonical: AWSURL
    metaDesc: String
    opengraphDescription: String
    opengraphModifiedTime: AWSDateTime
    opengraphPublishedTime: AWSDateTime
    opengraphTitle: String
    opengraphUrl: AWSURL
    opengraphImage: AWSURL
    twitterDescription: String
    twitterImage: String
    twitterTitle: String
    schemaSeo: String
}

type Comment
   {
  id: ID
  postId: ID!
  createdBy: ID
  author: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  text: String!
  likes: Int
}

type MediaObject @model {
    id: ID
    linkedId: ID
    createdBy: ID
    mediaItemUrl: AWSURL
    srcSet: String
    medium: AWSURL
    thumb: AWSURL
    sourceURL: AWSURL
    description: String
    bucket: String
    region: String
    key: String
    type: MediaObjectType
}

type Like @model {
    id: ID!
    objectVotedOnID: ID!
    createdBy: ID
    createdAt: AWSDateTime
    likeOn: LikeOnType

}

enum PostType {
    TOOLS
    BLOGS
    INSPIRATIONS
    NEWS
    POSTS
    NEWSLETTERS
}

enum LikeOnType {
    POST
    COMMENT
}

enum Status {
    PUBLISH
    DRAFT
}

enum MediaObjectType {
    IMAGE
    VIDEO
    AUDIO
}
```

Autogenerated (only CreatePostInput and CommentInput have been included for brevity), found in amplify > backend > api > build > schema.graphql:

```
input CreatePostInput {
  id: ID
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
  type: PostType!
  title: String!
  status: Status
  content: String!
  excerpt: String
  slug: AWSURL
  wordpressId: Int
  wordpressImageURLs: [AWSURL]
  author: String
  likes: Int
  comments: [CommentInput]
  numberOfComments: Int
}

input CommentInput {
  id: ID
  postId: ID!
  createdBy: ID
  author: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  text: String!
  likes: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else that notices this strange behaviour: The reason why `CommentInput` is included in the `CreatePostInput`, whilst the other custom types are not, is because `Comment` was the only type that I had forgot to label with an @model directive. I assume that this means that AppSync then views this type on the `comments` field as a set of nested fields, rather than an object with its own DynamoDB table. I have asked the AWS Amplify team and will update this answer when I hear more from them.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the example, you cited, Post and MediaObject have a one-to-many relationship. That is, a single Post has many MediaObjects. You won't see the many relations of a one-to-many generated on the parent object for mutations.

When creating a parent object that has children, you'll need to do this in 2 steps.

1. Create the parent object, and return the id.
2. Using the parentId, create the N child objects.

Here is some documentation from Amplify on how to do this: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/connection#has-many

Comment: Ok thanks very much for letting me know! Any idea why `seo`, `attributes`, and `featuredImage` aren't there?

Comment: I don't see any of your relationships being declared. Have a look through https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/connection and wire up the appropriate connection/keys for your specific use case.

Comment: Ok thanks for the pointer, but why is the comments array included in the CreatePostInput (as CommentInput) but the others aren’t? That’s what is confusing me :)